# Keyboard shortcut to open Terminal at the current folder location in Finder

Tags: finder, keybindings

Say I am in a Finder window (eg: ~/Documents/code ) and I want to be able to  use a keyboard shortcut to open a terminal window with the prompt

```
user@computer: ~/Documents/code$
```

Most of the questions are answered using mouse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** under **Files and Folders** there is a **New Terminal at Folder** shortcut which you can assign a keyboard shortcut to; however, it only appears on the **Finder** > **Services** menu, or the **right-click context menu**, when a **Folder** is selected. So if you have a **Finder** window open but no additional **folder** selected, it is not available. This may be fine for one's particular usage, but if not, then here is an alternative.

For example, say you have a **Finder** window open to your **Downloads** folder, which is selected in the **Sidebar**, and you want to open a **Terminal** window there. Well the built in *service* isn't available because an individual **Folder** isn't selected and what's selected in the **Sidebar** doesn't count...

One way to open a **Terminal** window at the location of the current **Finder** window, using a keyboard shortcut, is to use **AppleScript** in an **Automator** *Service* (*Quick Action* in **macOS Mojave**), then assign it a keyboard shortcut in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **...**

1. Create an **Automator** *Service* adding a **Run AppleScript** action, then replace the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below.
2. Save the *service* as e.g. **Open Terminal Here** with the settings as shown in the image below. Then assign it a keyboard shortcut. It should show under the **General** section of the aforementioned path.

   - **Note:** After assigning it a keyboard shortcut, you may have to trigger the new *service* one time with the mouse from the **Finder** > **Services** menu for it to work subsequently using the assigned keyboard shortcut.
   - Additionally, the assigned keyboard shortcut cannot be one that is already in use by **Finder**. I wanted to use **^⌘T** but it would not work, so I settled for: **^⌘\**
   - [Accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) for **Automator** may need to be granted for this service to work properly.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        set currentFolder to target of Finder window 1 as alias
    else
        return
    end if
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of currentFolder & "; clear"
    activate
end tell
```

[image: Automator Service]

---

As an added bonus, you can also use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* saved as an **AppleScript** *application* in **Script Editor** and place it in the **Toolbar** of **Finder**, thus allowing one to click the icon to open a **Terminal** window at the current location when one wants versus using the keyboard short assigned to the **Automator** *service*. No third-party app required!

1. In **Script Editor**, save the *example* **AppleScript** *code* as an **AppleScript** application, as e.g.: **Open Terminal Here**
2. In **Finder**, give it the same icon as **Terminal**.

   - From **Finder**, open the **Get Info** *sheet* for both the e.g.: **Open Terminal Here** app and **Terminal**, by selecting each and pressing: **⌘I**
   - With both **Get Info** *sheets* showing, select the icon in the upper left corner of the one for **Terminal** and press: **⌘C**
   - Now select the icon in the upper left corner of the one for e.g.: **Open Terminal Here** and press: **⌘V**
   - Close the **Get Info** *sheets*.
   - Drag an drop, while holding the **⌘** key<sup>1</sup>, the app bundle for the e.g.: **Open Terminal Here** app onto the **Toolbar** in **Finder**.

             <sup>1</sup> <sub>Required in later versions of **OS X/macOS**.</sub>

[image: Open Terminal Here on Finder's Toolbar]

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's very detailed and more complicated than I expected. I will get back to you very soon.

Comment: I wanted to say that your answer is working well.  But I had to fiddle with creating the service a bit. I had some difficulty in creating the automator service but I was finally able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: This is brilliant! Still working great on Big Sur on an M1 Mac

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd party app named gotoshell available at the Macapp Store for free. This app enables you to put a small icon on your finder window tool bar. When you click the icon, a terminal or iterm2 window opens at the same directory as the finder window. The icon appears on all finder windows. An image of icon is shown below.

[image]

Comment: The OP explicitly stated "I want to be able to use a keyboard shortcut to open a terminal window with the prompt" and further said "Most the the questions are answered using mouse.", so does the third-party app you've mentioned also allow assigning a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I assumed erroneously that he just wanted a simple way to open the terminal at the proper place. I will delete my answer shortly. I'd like for OP to at least read the answer because if he is using the Finder to go somewhere the app follows him and he just clicks it. If he's using the terminal to go somewhere then he doesn't need a shortcut.

Comment: He my be keyboard centric versus mouse centric and why he explicitly asked for a keyboard shortcut; however, I also included in my answer a way to use the existing code in a AppleScript application to be placed in the Toolbar of Finder for the occasion when one wants to click to get the same result. No third-party-app needed.

Comment: Yep your answer is spot on.  Its simple to do but you have to set it up and type the keyboard shortcut.  I was just offering the OP a slightly easier solution although its not keyboard centric as he requested...

Comment: @jmh I do navigate using mouse but sometimes when I am in folder, I open and close terminals a lot and would love to have a keyboard shortcut. Thanks for the solution anyway.